# JQuery Sortable - Sorting absolute positioned elements and placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, absolute

After fighting and fightings with this problem, I have no choice but ask for help! My situation is this: I have a number of **absolutely positioned** elements. Each of these elements has its own attributes "**top**" and "**left**". The HUGE problem I'm having with this is when I try to sort the items.

```
$(".container").sortable({
    containment: ".container",
    cursor: 'move',
    items: '.element',
    helper: 'clone',
    placeholder: 'new-placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    revert: true,
    scroll: false,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".new-placeholder").css("left", ui.helper.position().left);
        $(".new-placeholder").css("top", ui.helper.position().top);
        $(".new-placeholder").css("height", ui.helper.height());
        $(".new-placeholder").css("width", ui.helper.width());
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("Placeholder index: " + ui.placeholder.index());
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

This is the [Current Behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/fedeleoncba/K79KN/) and this is the [Expected behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/fedeleoncba/Zuxpn/)

As you can see, the elements should change their position when the dragged element is on over. Is there any better way to do this? I can't get rid of the absolute positions, that's the mainly issue. I know the solution have to be on the change, update and stop methods, but I can't figure this out by myself.

So far, all I got was to get the new index of the placeholder when the item is being dragged over another element but ¿how can I change the position of the placeholder and sort the rest of the elements according to that?

Comment: I also was using absolutely positioned elements. I could never get it to work with sortable. I had to create a new layout manager for my sortables so that it worked as well as (actually, better than) the original absolutely-positioned layout.

Comment: @greg-pettit Thanks for the answer! I'm still trying to make it work. Could you give me some approach ideas to implement the solution you said? Should I get rid of the sortable? As far as I can see, the sortable doesn't work with absolute positions at all. Even if I use relative positions, if I set top and left attributes using JQuery, the result is a mess after the sort.
Huge thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be impractical to reproduce all the elements, but the basic idea for my own update (to get it to work) was this:

1. Remove all absolute positioning from the container and the "portlets"
2. Each sortable container is floated left, is relatively positioned, and has a bottom padding. This padding means that even empty containers can be targeted
3. Each "portlet" within the container has width set to 100% and is also floated left with relative positioning and a bottom margin (to space them out).
4. Used the "start" parameter to set my placeholder sizes dynamically. I restrict placeholder size to 350px tall, but for any widgets smaller than that, the placeholder will equal the portlet size.
5. Used the "connectWith" parameter to link containers.

Basic HTML:

```
<div class="portletContainer"> <!-- floated left, has padding -->

  <div class="portlet"> <!-- floated left, margin-bottom, 100% width -->
    <div> some stuff </div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet"> <!-- floated left, margin-bottom, 100% width -->
    <div> some more stuff </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="portletContainer">
  <!-- repeat the above pattern; the two containers are then linked -->
</div>
```

Basic Sortable JavaScript:

```
$('.portletContainer').sortable({
  connectWith: ".portletContainer",
  start: function(e, ui) {
    var elementHeight = ui.item.height();
    if(elementHeight < 350) {
      ui.placeholder.height(elementHeight);
    }
  }
});
```

If that's still not working for you, something has likely just been overlooked. Either something is inheriting absolute positioning or JavaScript is adding it.

I think that covers all the bases, but the even shorter version is: I stripped it back until my markup and CSS was analogous to the markup and CSS in the "portlet" sample in the jQuery UI Sortable Demo page.

Comment: That's exactly the approach I was needing. I definitely need to change my HTML structure in order to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this. You can use some CSS trickery with the `nth-child` or `nth-type-of` selector to apply your absolute positioning to indices rather than directly to elements. Thus, when items shift around in the DOM tree due to how the sortable plugin works, they'll capture the correct position attributes since the indices will stay the same.

The other way is using the `sortchange` event of the plugin which fires whenever the order of the items in your list is changed. Thus, in the event function, you need to iterate through your items and re-apply the correct positioning.

Check [here](http://www.nightcrawler.ro/2014/01/jquery-sortable-with-absolute-position.html) for more details on how to use both methods: